# jQuery Clone Div content into Textarea

Tags: jquery, html

I want to clone div content to textarea. It works fine from Div to Div, but not from Div to Textarea. I have no idea what Im missing. Can you guys please help me on this?

**Current jQuery**

```
$('.policyCopyBtn').click(function(){
    $('.leftPart').clone().appendTo('.policyDetails');
});
```

**Current HTML**

```
<div class="leftPart">Some text here</div>
<div class="rightPart"><textarea class="policyDetails"></textarea></div>
<input type="submit" class="policyCopyBtn" />
```

JS FIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/c2fny59x/

***I cant use .html() because this will copy all my formatting in the DIV as well. I just want plain text copied across.***

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/c2fny59x/2/

Comment: This copies all HTML tags into the textarea. So if I have <p> in the div, it shows in textarea as well. I just want plain text copied

Comment: try now https://jsfiddle.net/c2fny59x/3/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen you should put it as answer

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen it doesnt work when I have <p> inside the div. https://jsfiddle.net/c2fny59x/4/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c2fny59x/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the `text` using `text()` and set the `text` using `val()`.

```
$('.policyCopyBtn').click(function() {
   var text = $('.leftPart').text();
   $('textarea').val(text);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `val()` function to set value of text area, `text()` function gives inner text.

```
<div class="leftPart"><p>
Text from paragraph
</p>Some text here</div>
<div class="rightPart">
  <textarea id="textA"class="policyDetails"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="policyCopyBtn" />


  $('.policyCopyBtn').click(function() {
   $('#textA').val($('.leftPart').text());
 });
```

Comment: This copies all HTML tags into the textarea. So if I have <p> in the div, it shows in textarea as well. I just want plain text copied

Comment: Use text() function, I have updated my answer as per your requirement. Please check again. Also you can use trim() function to remove edditional spacing $('.leftPart').text().trim()

Comment: Nasty accepts the answer if this meets your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Simply, in your `JS` append the `.leftPart` text contents to `.policyDetails` textarea. Here's the working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x346my5j/

```
$('.policyCopyBtn').click(function() {
   $('.policyDetails').append($('.leftPart').text());
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all the tags with "".

```
 $('.policyCopyBtn').click(function() {
  $('.policyDetails').val($('.leftPart').html().replace(/<[^>]+>/ig,""));
 });
```

Check the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c2fny59x/8/ . 
I hope this helps.

Comment: No need to do replace if you use `.text()`